# How can a custom gradle task be ran from the body of a build

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have the following custom plugin:

```
class GenPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
   void apply(Project project) {
      project.task("gen", type:GenTask)
   }
}
```

That adds the following task to the project:

```
class GenTask extends DefaultTask {

   @TaskAction
   def gen() {
      println "hello"
   }
}
```

The groovy code is packaged and deployed to a local maven repository, I then reference the dependency in a build with:

```
apply plugin: 'gen'
```

I can run the task successfully by using `gradle gen`, how can I run this task in my build.gradle without specifying it as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `defaultTasks`, have a look at the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:default_tasks).

Running the task from gradle itself is highly discouraged. You can do it with:

```
project.tasks.gen.execute()
```

however I don't recommend you to go that way. Instead you can define a dependency on the task you run from command line. If this task is called e.g. `afterGen`, then use:

```
afterGen.dependsOn gen
```

Comment: How can I just run the task from a build.gradle? I don't want to specify it as default because I will need to run it at a specific phase of the life cycle